# Why doesn't javascript code works after an ajax request using struts2 and dojo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, struts2, dojo

I'm using DOJO in Struts2 for Ajax support. After a request, a users list is shown in a table inside a dialog box via Ajax.

Every user in this list must contain a link to the user detail, which is to be shown inside another dialog box via Ajax.

Here is the html of the column that contains the link:

```
<td>
    <s:url id="mostrar_usuario_url" action="mostrar_usuario.action">
        <s:param name="id_usuario" value="%{id_usuario}"/>
    </s:url>
    <sx:a cssClass="mostrar_usuario_link" id="mostrar_usuario_link_%{id_usuario}" targets="mostrar_usuario_dialog" href="%{mostrar_usuario_url}">
        <s:property value="id_usuario"/>
    </sx:a>
</td>
```

It successfully gets the user information and the html, however the dialog box that is supposed to show the info is not launched.

This is the script for the dialog box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buscar_usuarios_dialog").on("click", ".mostrar_usuario_link", function() {
            $("#mostrar_usuario_dialog").dialog({
            modal:true
        }) 
    })
})
```

"buscar_usuarios_dialog" is the id of a div that contains the table.

The problem is the ajax works perfectly but the javascript does not. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As I said in your previous question . Perhaps you need to use preventDefault as the element is an anchor tag?

```
$("document").on("click", ".mostrar_usuario_link", function(e) {
    //Prevent Default action from link
    e.preventDefault();
    ...
});
```

Without seeing it in a fiddle, with an example of your generated HTML - here's an example of what I imagine your structure is similar to, and it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/6tqvj/

Comment: I'm sorry, i didn't get to read that. The problem is it doesn't even get into the function because the event "click" is never triggered.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide an example on http://jsfiddle.net ? It is quite hard to tell without the rest of the code. I realise you probably can't just put the Struts2 code in there, but if you just use the generated HTML perhaps.